# How to catch already caught exception?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, exception

I have the follow the following filter:

```
@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException,
     ServletException {

  try {
     chain.doFilter(new XSSRequestWrapper((HttpServletRequest) request), response);
  } catch (XssAttackException e) {
     request.getRequestDispatcher("/XssAttack").forward(request, response);
  }
}
```

and the class `XssAttackException` is:

```
public class XssAttackException extends RuntimeException {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

}
```

after debugging the code, I realized that somewhere in the spring framework all the exceptions are being caught. Now I need a way that my catch bock also run.

> UPDATE

inside `XSSRequestWrapper` we have:

```
@Override
public String getHeader(String name) {

  String value = super.getHeader(name);
  return stripXSS(value);
}
```

And

```
private String stripXSS(String value) {

  if (value != null) {
     value = persianUtf8(value);
     if (!value.equals(Jsoup.parse(value).text())) {
        throw new XssAttackException();
     }
     value = Jsoup.parse(value).text();
     for (Pattern scriptPattern : patterns) {
        if (scriptPattern.matcher(value).matches()) {
           throw new XssAttackException();
        }
        value = scriptPattern.matcher(value).replaceAll("");
     }
  }
  return value;
}
```

Comment: somewhere where? maybe the exception is being throwing in  previous filter?

Comment: where XssAttackException comes from? what is fully qualified class name  and jar file? I am not able to find that class in Spring.

Comment: @Leo no my debugging shows that it is the exact class of XssAttackException

Comment: @BartoszBilicki It is my own class intended for Xss Attack in my app

Comment: @Leo the catch block in spring framework catches Exception types, the root class of every exceptions.

Comment: Have you hooked in this filter via web.xml? If so then look at hooking it in via Spring instead.

Comment: I am confused with your question , did you catch the exception ? I mean your code was reached inside  catch block ? What is your filter mapping and springDispatcher servlet mapping ?

Comment: @Cataclysm No I have not, the only problem is this, the application never falls into my catch block. I want to redirect the response which has script attack to an error page.

Comment: If so the only problem is your catch block can't handle exception type. You are using wrong catching. The exception type mismatch. So , catch some general exception (Exception,RuntimeException,ServletException) and rethrow your custom exception as `throw new XssAttackException(..)` and handle it from another.

Comment: Do you think `chain.doFilter(new XSSRequestWrapper((HttpServletRequest) request), response);` will throw `XssAttackException` when error was occured ? I don't think so , `doFilter` method will throw Servlet Exception and your catch Exception type can't handle it. So Exception was go up to StackTrace and reached it to Spring Container.

Comment: @Cataclysm I agree with the approach, but the only thing is, the catch block which is handle the exceptions(all the exceptions extended from Exception class including mine) is in the jar file of Spring Framework.

Comment: If so make a new method `myProcess()` and handle your custom exception yourself *(make throw some exception or forward request)*. And call your method instead directly calling `chain.doFilter...`.

Comment: Please see the update guys. Thanks.

Comment: what is *"persianUtf8"* supposed to be? There is no such thing ... thats like writing "chinese english"

Comment: @specializt it is a function changing Arabic characters to corresponding Persians. BTW the question is focusing on different thing.

Comment: so you're **manipulating** incoming requests?? Thats ... the weirdest thing i have read today. You probably should fix the requesting clients instead of your server

Comment: do you see your exception in logs? if you enable DEBUG for every class, and spring indeed catches your exception, you should see it in logs. Most likely, class that logs the exception catches it a few lines earlier. So you will have an answer who catches your exception.

Answer (score 0):

Please don't assume this is answer for your question.Assumed too long comment.
I created my CustomException class.

```
public class CustomException extends RuntimeException {
}
```

and created custom Servlet class as your XSSRequestWrapper and throw my custom exception in constructor.

```
public class MyServlet implements ServletRequest {

    public MyServlet() {
        throw new CustomException();
    }
// other override methods go here
}
```

and in my filter class

```
    try {
        chain.doFilter(new MyServlet(), response);
    } catch (CustomException e) {
        System.out.println("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx I got it xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
    }
```

This code work fine. At your program , I think there has some exception has occured and you did not catch on them. So , this exception object has miss from your try block of your filter class and handled by Spring container.